# Let f : $X \to Y$ with right inverse g: $Y \to X$, if f has one and only one right inverse, than it is injective.

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I want to prove the following thing:

Let f : $X \to Y$ with right inverse g: $Y \to X$, if f has one and only one right inverse, then it is injective.

I know that if a function g is a right inverse then f $\circ$ g = $Id_y$.

My proof is by contradiction, but I do not think it is very rigorous.

If f is not injective, then we would have $g(y_1) \neq g(y_2) \rightarrow f(g(y_1) = f(g(y_2)$ which is equivalent to: $g(y_1) \neq g(y_2) \rightarrow y_1 = y_2$

But this is not possible because the right nverse is unique.

Can this argument work?

Comment: Your argument is not valid. If f is not injective you can only say there exist $x_1 \neq x_2$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. You are assuming that we can take $x_1=g(y_1)$ and $x_2=g(y_2)$ for some $y_1$ and $y_2$.

Comment: No, this can't be possibily true. Rather f injective iff there exists a left inverse